# Working with Query String in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, query-string

```
"~/ActiveGoals.aspx?UserName={0}?SUName={1}"
```

This is a URL which will be redirected after a click event.

after that i want to utilize the second part of the QueryString i,e, SUName.

Comment: you are missing `&` i think it should be `"~/ActiveGoals.aspx?UserName={0}&SUName={1}"`

Comment: So whats the issue ? Here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: `Request.QueryString["SUName"]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like

```
"~/ActiveGoals.aspx?UserName={0}&SUName={1}"
```

not

```
"~/ActiveGoals.aspx?UserName={0}?SUName={1}"
```

and then you get SUName from code behind

```
string str=Request.QueryString["SUName"];
```